# i want to understand how this coding is working [php]

Tags: php, templates

this is the tpl file used show GUI of something. i posted it all. how this code read the tpl file and show HTML display. which command is doing this.

```
class Template {

/**
 * Config
 *
 * @access private 
 */ 
private static $config;

/**
 * Path templates
 * 
 * @access private
 */
private $tpl_path = null;

/**
 * Values
 * 
 * @access private
 */
private $values = array();

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @access public
 */ 
public function __construct($tpl_path) {

    self::$config = config_load('template');

    $this->tpl_path = $tpl_path;

}

/**
 * Set a template variable
 * 
 * @access public
 */
public function set($name, $value = null) {

    if(is_array($name)) {

        foreach ($name as $key => $value) {

            $this->values[$key] = $value;

        }

    } else {

        $this->values[$name] = $value;

    }

}

/**
 * Display the template file
 * 
 * @access public
 */
public function display($template) {

    if ($this->values) {

        extract($this->values);

    }  

    if (file_exists($this->tpl_path . $template . self::$config['template_extension'])) {

        ob_start();

        include($this->tpl_path . $template . self::$config['template_extension']);

        $output = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

    } else {

        die('Template file '. $this->tpl_path . $template . self::$config['template_extension'] . ' not found.');

    }

    if ($output) echo $output;

} 

     }

      ?>
```

i have the file which is using this class and the code is

```
     $tpl->set('customer_details', $customer_details);
     $tpl->set('customer_addresses', $customer_addresses);
     $tpl->set('countries', $countries);

      //Display the template
       $tpl->display('edit_account');
```

the above code is using tpl and setting values. but how the values are set and displayed

Comment: Then you should reseach ever line of code you do not understand

Comment: A hint: the `include` is the access to the template file, the echo the output.

Comment: if ($this->values) {

        extract($this->values);

    }  what these lines doing

Comment: David... [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) It all started here, remember you volunteered

Comment: unable to uderstand extract in php manual. i know this is doing this. but i want to know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.  The class code uses php [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).  The templates can freely intermix php and HTML just as any php file can, and variables will be interpolated. The class uses output buffering to store the output and then using echo returns the output.  Variables used in the class are provided generically using the set method that puts them all into a class array variable named 'values' which is undoubtably referenced in the template files.

Comment: self::$config = config_load('template');  ///→what his code is doing config_load('TEMPLATE') I know the basics but cant understand the flow of the program.

Comment: The self::$config line, is setting the value of the static class variable using a function named config_load.  You didn't provide all the code but this function is being included so that it's globally available inside the class. This is probably in whatever bootstrap code is involved.  Not great design or practice, but that is how it works.  Just find the declaration for function config_load(...)  Later that variable is used to look for a particular file extension string (self::$config['template_extension']).